# Flipping along two axis in a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to perform some numerical calculations and in it, I have to flip the first and second dimensions of a multidimensional array. I tried it with two methods and I noticed that the first one gives the wrong output and the second method gives the correct output. Here is the code for both:

```
for i in range(I):
    for j in range(J):
        w[:,:,i,j] = np.fliplr(w[:,:,i,j])
        w[:,:,i,j] = np.flipud(w[:,:,i,j])
```

versus:

```
w = w[::-1,::-1,:,:]
```

I decided to try a small test case to see what was going on and it looks like both methods are actually giving the same answer:

```
a = np.array([[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]])
print a[:,::-1,::-1]
print a.shape

(I,J,K) = a.shape
for i in range(I):
    a[i,:,:] = np.fliplr(a[i,:,:])
    a[i,:,:] = np.flipud(a[i,:,:])
print a
print a.shape
```

Could my issue be somewhere in my code or is there something fundamentally different between the two that I am missing?

Comment: Look at the code for the `flip` functions.  They just apply the `::-1` indexing to different dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the code for the flip functions. They just apply the ::-1 indexing to different dimensions

```
def fliplr
    m = asanyarray(m)
    if m.ndim < 2:
        raise ValueError("Input must be >= 2-d.")
    return m[:, ::-1]
    # ud: m[::-1, ...]
```

So anything they can do, you can do directly with `::-1` indexing.